# Overlay of multiple time series in Quantmod in R

Tags: r, charts, quantmod

I want to create a chart using chartSeries with two or more time series on the SAME chart (overlaying each other). Bing/search doc have gotten me nowhere. Seems like should be fairly easy, I tried addTA, but didn't work. I tried the following code.

```
chartSeries(c(PSEC, ARCC), type = "line")
```

That resulted into this: (nevermind the fonts, the hell is the green blob?)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The green blob is what you asked R to plot. `c(PSEC, ARCC)` is the same as `rbind(PSEC, ARCC)`, which creates a single OHLCVA object with two observations per index value (one for PSEC, one for ARCC).  You said you tried `addTA`, but it "didn't work".  Saying something "doesn't work" does not help people help you, especially when you don't even show the code that "doesn't work".

Here's a `chartSeries` call that uses `addTA`, and a corresponding `chart_Series` version.  Note that `chart_Series` automatically handles the y-axis range for you.

```
> chartSeries(Cl(PSEC), TA="addTA(Cl(ARCC), on=1)")
> chart_Series(Cl(PSEC), TA="add_TA(Cl(ARCC), on=1)")
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm embarrassed. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your data, if it is not daily, could easily look like a green blob.

For example, if that's minute-by-minute prices, I'd expect it to look like this upon visual inspection.

Comment: The data is daily. I suspect the top of the green area is one stock and the bottom is the  other one.